# Making image travel towards mouse cursor

Tags: java, image, mouse

In the game im making I want to use the mouse cursor to aim with. This is the code I have for know to make the bullet move towards the mouse cursor:

Locating the mouse position
    private PointerInfo mouse = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    private Point point = new Point(mouse.getLocation());
Making the bullet kinda move towards the mouse cursor

```
if(point.getX() > player.getX()){
        setX(getX() + 1);
}
if(point.getX() < player.getX()){
        setX(getX() - 1);
}
if(point.getY() > player.getY()){
        setY(getY() + 1);
}
if(point.getY() < player.getY()){
        setY(getY() - 1);
}
```

The problem is that the bullet won't travel precisly to the mouse cursor but travel in a 45 degree path dow to the left if the mouse cursor is somewhere in that area, the same thing goes for up to the left, down to the right and up to the right.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @RobWatts Yes they are

Comment: Should bullets follow the cursor, or head in the direction of where the cursor was when they were fired?

Comment: @RobWatts head in the direction of where the cursor was when they were fired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make the bullets move directly toward the cursor and not always in 45 degree paths, use `double` for your internal representation of X and Y. Also, since you want the bullet to head in a certain direction, you'll want to compute the X velocity and Y velocity when you first create the bullet.

For example:

```
double deltaX = player.getX() - point.getX();
double deltaY = player.getY() - point.getY();
double magnitude = Math.sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);

// It's possible for magnitude to be zero (cursor is over the person)
// Decide what you want the default direction to be to handle that case
double xVelocity = 1;
double yVelocity = 0;
if (magnitude != 0) {
    xVelocity = deltaX / magnitude;
    yVelocity = deltaY / magnitude;
}
```

With the velocities computed when you first create the bullet, at each tick you just need to use `xPosition += xVelocity` and `yPosition += yVelocity`.

Comment: `double deltaX = x - point.getX();
        double deltaY = y - point.getY();
        double deltaXX = deltaX * deltaX;
        double deltaYY = deltaY * deltaY;
        double magnitude = Math.sqrt(deltaXX = deltaYY);
        double xVelocity = 1;
        double yVelocity = 0;
        if (magnitude != 0) {
            xVelocity = deltaX / magnitude;
            yVelocity = deltaY / magnitude;
        }
        x += xVelocity;
        y += yVelocity;`

Comment: Why does the bullet go int the exact oposite direction of the mouse cursor and whydo the bullet have different speed depending on where im aiming?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the magnitude calculation (used = when I meant +). See if that helps.

Comment: And as for going in the opposite direction, try switching the `deltaX` and `deltaY` calculations, i.e `deltaX = point.getX() - x`.

Comment: now it does move in the same speed and it goes in the right direction but for some reason the bullets stop at a random location after they have traveled for a certain distance. This is a picture of how it looks like: [link](http://imgur.com/DjNYi3u)

Comment: It seems like it travels until it gets to the mouse cursor

Comment: Also, how would I make the bullet move faster whitout messing everything up?

Comment: To make the bullet move faster, have a variable called `bulletSpeed` and change the assignment lines to `xVelocity = bulletSpeed*deltaX/magnitude`.

To make bullets continue past the mouse cursor, calculate `xVelocity` and `yVelocity` once for each bullet, then use that same value until the bullet leaves the screen.